# Attributes not showing in sidebar categories

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1

I have multiple products in my store which all have options or attributes like color, brand, size etc. I am working on a new shop which is located here: tfgsnew.hypernode.io. I cannot find out why it is not showing my shopping information on the left sidebar here:

http://tfgsnew.hypernode.io/fietsen/alle-fietsen

[image: Sidebar]

My theme builder cant find the problem either. Where should I start looking in settings or where can it go wrong? It doesn't display. It should be like this (located here: http://mas1.magikthemes.com/index.php/aspire/womens/clothing.html) :

[image: Theme version]

What is going wrong?